# Passing property values the efficient way

Tags: javascript

I have a function here that calls a specific property from an object inside an array.

Each object has multiple properties, so right now I am using multiple functions to call specific properties like so. I know that this is terribly inefficient and that this could be much more efficient.

```
var fiftyplanets = [{
    "Hostname": "11 Com",
    "Distance [pc]": 110.62,
    "Effective Temperature [K]": 4742,
    "Date of Last Update": "5/14/2014"
}];

function findDistance(hostname) {
    function search(am, im) {
        if (am.Hostname === hostname) {
            index = im;
            return true;
        }
    }

    var index;
    if (fiftyplanets.some(search)) {
        return fiftyplanets[index]['Distance [pc]'];
    }
}

function findTemp(hostname) {
    function search(am, im) {
        if (am.Hostname === hostname) {
            index = im;
            return true;
        }
    }

    var index;
    if (fiftyplanets.some(search)) {
        return fiftyplanets[index]['Effective Temperature [K]'];
    }
}

var name = value;
var resullt = fiftyplanets.indexOf(name);
var dist = findDistance(name);
var temp = findTemp(name);
```

How can I efficiently write the above function so that I  look for specific properties using just one function?

Comment: Unless there is a particular error or issue you are having I would recommend moving your question to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I didn't know such a site existed. Is there a migration tool or something that can pass this question to that site? Or do I have to delete this one and copy/paste it there?

Comment: [There's an answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85017/how-do-i-move-my-own-question-to-another-stack-exchange-site) that has some good info. I'll flag for moderator attention to see if it can be moved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but it gets rid of the reused code and puts the search into one funcion.

```js
var fiftyplanets = [{
    "Hostname": "11 Com",
    "DistancePc": 110.62,
    "effectiveTemperatureK": 4742,
    "dateOfLastUpdate": "5/14/2014"
}];

function getInfo(info, hostname ) {
    function search(am, im) {
        if (am.Hostname === hostname) {
            index = im;
            return true;
        }
    }

    var index;
    if (fiftyplanets.some(search)) {
        return fiftyplanets[index][info];
    }
}

var name = value;
var resullt = fiftyplanets.indexOf(name);
var dist = getInfo('DistancePc', name);
```